# Welche Teile von „Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen“ schreibt man groß, welche Teile klein?

Tags: compound, capitalization

Betrachten wird das Beispiel

> In der Ungleichung „4 ⩽ 5“ steht nach dem Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen die Fünf.

Ist die Klein- und Großschreibung in „Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen“ richtig?  Wenn ja: warum? Wenn nein: wie wäre es richtig?

Comment: Mehr als Anmerkung an Rande: Vielleicht wäre es einen Gedanken wert, dieses Wortungetüm ganz zu vermeiden und allgemeiner von einem [Vergleichszeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vergleichszeichen) zu sprechen. Oder man spricht von der linken bzw. rechten Seite der [Ungleichung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungleichung).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Stimmt, das ist ein Wortungetüm, aber so würde es nicht funktionieren. Zwar ist jedes Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen ein Vergleichszeichen, aber nicht jedes Vergleichszeichen ein Kog-Zeichen, etc.. Und Ungleichungen kann man gleichrangig umdrehen. Damit wäre nichts gewonnen. Eher im Gegenteil.

Comment: Als Anmerkung ... wird das Symbol nicht normalerweise sprachökononmischer als Kleiner-gleich-Zeichen bezeichnet? Also ohne "oder".

Comment: @mtwde Wir haben hier aber den klaren Bezug auf eine konkrete Ungleichung. Die ist so, wie sie da steht, egal ob man sie umdrehen könnte oder nicht. Und auch welches Vergleichszeichen gemeint ist dadurch klar, nämlich das was da steht ;) In Fällen wie "3x <= 4z <= 20" muss man halt vom "ersten Vergleichszeichen" etc. sprechen.

Comment: Ich bin schon seit mehr als 15 Jahren Mathematiker und muss ich sagen, dass ich das Wort "Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen" noch nie gehört oder gesehen habe. Wir sprechen immer nur von "Ungleichungen" und deren Seiten (rechte/linke) bzw. von "Ungleichheitszeichen" (darunter fallen paradoxerweise <, >, <=, >=, aber nicht != ). (Ich hätte ja gerne LaTeX-Markup $<$, $>$, $\leq$, $\geq$ und $\neq$ verwendet, aber das wird auf dieser anscheinend nicht unterstützt.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Wie antwortest du denn auf die Frage: "Welches Ungleichheitszeichen wird in der vom OP genannten Ungleichung verwendet?"

Comment: "Vergleichszeichen" ist unspezifischer und damit kein gleichwertiger Ersatz. "Wortungetüm" sehe ich auch als ziemliche Übertreibung an, aber "Kleinergleichzeichen" wäre eine Alternative, die auf einen Wortbestandteil verzichtet, bleiben also 3, wie in Seelachsfilet, Kirschbaumkommode oder Wintersportsaison. Ich bin kein Mathematiker und habe immer wieder mit diesen Zeichen und deren Bezeichnung zu tun.

Answer (score 4):

Die Schreibweise stimmt, zumindest ist: https://www.mathetreff-online.de/wissen/mathelexikon/kleiner-oder-gleich-zeichen der gleichen Meinung wie du.

Das Wort muss mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnen, da es als Ganzes ein Substantiv ist. Die Teile innerhalb des Wortes werden so geschrieben, wie sie auch in einem normalen Satz (ohne Bindestriche) stehen würden.

Answer (score 4):

Komposita werden im Deutschen normalerweise als ein Wort geschrieben, wie zum Beispiel der berühmte Donaudampfschiffkapitän und seine Mütze.

Jedoch gibt es auch die [Durchkopplung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung#Anwendung).

> Besteht die Bestimmung [...] aus einer Gruppe von mehreren Wörtern, Zahlen oder Einzelbuchstaben, die sonst in der Regel durch Leerzeichen getrennt sind, so werden zur Bildung des Kompositums alle einzelnen Bestandteile durch Bindestriche verbunden (durchgekoppelt).

Bespiele wären ([aus Rat der dt. Rechtschreibung §44 (1)](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf#page=43)):

> Kopf-an-Kopf-Rennen, Mund-zu-Mund-Beatmung, Wort-für-Wort-Übersetzung, Als-ob-Philosophie

Für deren Groß- bzw Kleinschreibung gilt

> Das erste Wort des Kompositums (sofern es sich bei dem Kompositum um ein Substantiv handelt) sowie substantivische Bestandteile werden dabei in der Regel großgeschrieben.

Insofern wäre ⩽ ein

> Kleiner-oder-gleich-Zeichen

bzw. wie ich es kenne

> Kleiner-gleich-Zeichen

**EDIT**

Wie @userunknown in den Kommentaren korrekt anmerkt kann man die Variante Kleiner-gleich-Zeichen auch ohne Bindestriche verwenden, also

> Kleinergleichzeichen

Beispiele für die Schreibweise als ein Wort finden sich etwa in [Ralf Walters Einführung in die Analysis, Band 1](https://books.google.de/books?id=b1j0wYiIIiMC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22Kleinergleichzeichen%22&source=bl&ots=qV_xePq6PZ&sig=ACfU3U3t3iDYJyB_zUQGFLbwRpmUkOuFsA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq4se1leHnAhUdSxUIHXmFCMYQ6AEwEnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Kleinergleichzeichen%22&f=false) oder [Guido Walz' Lexikon der Mathematik: Band 5](https://books.google.de/books?id=0iagDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=%22Kleinergleichzeichen%22&source=bl&ots=_aIlzB-9Nh&sig=ACfU3U1x2vQMsxpGfELK8f_cFP-MvLjEDA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq4se1leHnAhUdSxUIHXmFCMYQ6AEwD3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Kleinergleichzeichen%22&f=false)

Beispiele für die Schreibweise mit Bindestrich sind in [Benjamin R. Auers Grundkurs Wirtschaftsmathematik](https://books.google.de/books?id=2m4pBAAAQBAJ&pg=PR18&dq=%22kleiner-gleich-zeichen%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiwd-ZluHnAhUkpnEKHUmiAXUQ6AEIWDAF#v=onepage&q=%22kleiner-gleich-zeichen%22&f=false) oder [Alexander Markowich Ostrowski Vorlesungen über Differential- und Integralrechnung](https://books.google.de/books?id=HunPAAAAMAAJ&q=%22kleiner-gleich-zeichen%22&dq=%22kleiner-gleich-zeichen%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig2tGbmOHnAhVOiFwKHTzNDRI4ChDoAQhEMAQ)

Und schließlich die Variante mit oder findet sich in [Alan Schwartz SpamAssassin](https://books.google.de/books?id=-N7FZA87E3QC&pg=PA215&dq=%22Kleiner-oder-gleich-zeichen%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUrPq4mOHnAhUIY8AKHWvlBZwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Kleiner-oder-gleich-zeichen%22&f=false), wobei diese Variante die mit der geringsten Verbreitung in Büchern zu sein scheint, wenn man Google glauben darf.

Comment: Wenn Du das "oder" weglässt, was ich unterstütze, kannst Du auch, wie https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungleichung Wikipedia, Kleinergleichzeichen schreiben.